# C# - Using user-secrets import in all class of a project

Tags: c#, .net-core, user-secret

I've written a console app using user-secrets:

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                           .AddUserSecrets<Program>()
                           .Build();

Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

Console.WriteLine("Parametro: " + configuration["test"]);

Prova p = new Prova();
p.prova();
```

I want to use configuration in a new class `Prova`. How can I do that without reconfiguring the user-secrets?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Inject configuration as a dependency

```
public Prova(IConfiguration config)
{
     var secret = config[“secret”]
}
```